# error in process filter: Invalid byte opcode: op=183, ptr=6

Tags: mu4e

I am installing `mu4e`. Pulling email and indexing with `mu` both work. But calling `M-x mu4e` gives:

```
error in process filter: Invalid byte opcode: op=183, ptr=6
```

In addition, if I add these lines to `~/.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'mu4e-bookmarks
       (make-mu4e-bookmark
        :name "Inbox"
        :query "maildir:/Exchange/INBOX"
        :key ?i))
```

I am unable to even load it:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: record
```

The same code works with my colleagues. How can I fix it?

Comment: What version of emacs are you using?

Comment: Elisp which was byte-compiled on an older version of Emacs will also run on newer versions; but the reverse does not necessarily apply, as the language continues to evolve over time.  I prefer to install the same version of Emacs on all the systems I use, as it side-steps the whole issue of cross-version compatibility for my config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me you're using an Elisp package that was compiled with a more recent Emacs than the Emacs you're using.

So, either recompile that Elisp package with your older Emacs, or stop using that older Emacs and use the newer one instead.